# Applications of logarithm

Tags: calculus

In an experimental environment , the population of a type of insert was observed . After $t$ days, the number of insects $N$ was given by the equation $N= 500 + 5000e^{kt} $ , where $k$ is a constant . Given that the population of the insects decreased to 5000 after 3 days . 
After a Long period of time , the population of the insects approached a particular values A, what is A ?

I found the constant $k = -0.03512$ and the initial population is $5500$

Hence the new equation is -

$$N= 500 + 5000e^{-0.03512t}$$

They didn't give the value of $t$ , how am I suppose to find $A$ ? My bet is simultaneously. But I'm not sure how to form the 2 equations and what are they.

Comment: you have to do $t\to \infty$. If you do that, what do you get?

Comment: The second term vanishes and the A = 500.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to two differents ways:

1: Take $t \rightarrow \infty$ and see what happens;

2: Let $N=A$, and use the $log$ to find $t$ in terms of $A$.

For $1$:
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} N(t) = 500$$
Because

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{−0.03512t} \rightarrow 0. $$